Problem with properly aligning buttons on website
I have been trying for a good while, and looked online for how to properly align the UI of the website, but whatever I tried never managed to work on it, it either flipped it back to a vertical layout or interfered with the navbar.
First time using html and css, so there is a lot of learning involved with this. any feedback/solution would be appriciated.
Goal: To get the five buttons that are in a row on the Website to be to  be at the center of the screen, instead of the right under the navbar.
Html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles_home.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Medication reminder</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'profile_home' %}"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'settings' %}""><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li class="end">
                <form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i>Logout</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="dashboard.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-border-all"></i> <br>Dashboard
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="calendar.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> <br>Schedule
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="events.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-circle-exclamation"></i> <br>Events
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="analysis.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> <br> Analysis
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="configuration.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-sliders"></i> <br>Configuration
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

and the css code:
:root {
    --text: #10150f;
    --background: #fafbf9;
    --primary: #799d72;
    --secondary: #aac4b7;
    --accent: #92b3a7;
    --shadow: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.2)
}
  

body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: var(--background);
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: var(--background); /* Adjust background color as needed */
    padding: 20px 20px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 var(--shadow), 0 6px 20px 0 var(--shadow);
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar li {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px; /* Adjust margin between items as needed */
}

.navbar li.end {
    margin-right: 0; /* No margin for the "end" item */
    margin-left: auto; /* Push the "end" item to the right */
}

.navbar i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.navbar button, a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--text); /* Adjust button text color as needed */
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
}


.navbar button:hover {
    color: #3b5447;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

}

.row ul {
    display: flex; /* Use flexbox */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow items to wrap to the next row if needed */
    justify-content: center; /* Horizontally center the items */
    padding: 0; /* Remove default padding */
    margin: 0; /* Remove default margin */
}

.row li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.row i {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.row a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: var(--text);
}

.row a:hover {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
}

Current UI of the Website
Tried to change the display from flex to block, which didnt work, as i couldnt get a proper row direction afterwards. Tried adding a container class before the row class in html, and then tried to configure it to center, this didnt work either. Tried a bunch of small changes also, and even asked chatgpt to help, to no success.

You’ve included most of the parts a good question needs, so well done for that. However, it’s not clear to me what your goal is. Please edit your question to include a clear description of your goal, and how your results to-date differ from that goal.

You can only "center" stuff, in either direction, if you have more space to distribute to begin with, than the width/height of the content requires. In the height "direction", you don't have that here. Your .container element will only be as high as its own content requires - so there is nothing to center, in that direction. So you need to get that element to grow beyond what its content requires first of all - for example by using the flexbox layout module.

As @Brett Donald already mentioned in his comment, it is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve in the first place, but I'm going to lay down some guidelines here for you. In case you wanted to center the buttons vertically, you somehow need to tell the .container div to take up more height, as the content is then automatically centered for you using a CSS property align-content: center for flexbox.
Another quick thing, maybe I misinterpreted the code for this, but I think that the .row div is a bit redundant, you can achieve the same result with just the first parent div of the buttons and change the styling to be something along the following lines:
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    height: 89vh;
}

.container ul {
    display: flex; /* Use flexbox */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow items to wrap to the next row if needed */
    justify-content: center; /* Horizontally center the items */
    padding: 0; /* Remove default padding */
    margin: 0; /* Remove default margin */
}

.container li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.container i {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.container a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: var(--text);
}

.container a:hover {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
}

And remove the .row div from HTML:
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="dashboard.html">
                <i class="fas fa-border-all"></i> <br>Dashboard
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="calendar.html">
                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> <br>Schedule
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="events.html">
                <i class="fas fa-circle-exclamation"></i> <br>Events
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="analysis.html">
                <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> <br> Analysis
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="configuration.html">
                <i class="fas fa-sliders"></i> <br>Configuration
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

In my case I explicitly defined the height of the container div, but this is usually not the preferred solution, since you might want your website to be reactive to different screen ratios or sizes, in that case you might need to look into css @media queries.
